# entity name not functioning properly

Tags: java, html, xhtml

Trying to convert html to xhtml but when i change my greater than sign to `&gt;` my if statement doesnt work anymore. Same story with `&` and `<` sign. Cdata doesnt work either.

```
function length(elem){
    var input = elem.value;
    if(input.length &gt; 8){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter equal to or more than 8 characters for username");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you writing embedded javascript? Why not use `>`?

Comment: because xhtml doesnt accept > sign

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: Don't use XHTML. In most cases, it is far more trouble then it is worth.

Failing that: Keep your JS in external files and load them via `src`.

Failing that, see [the compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4) for writing XHTML and then having it treated as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to “escape” the “>” character, in HTML, XHTML, or XML, except if you like to do so for symmetry with “<”, which often needs to be escaped.

In XHTML, the content of `script` is taken as `#PCDATA`, which means that entity references are recognized. So `&gt;` would be OK, but this only applies to browsers that *really* process the document as XHTML; in practice, you would need to declare an XML content type and accept the fact that old versions of IE will choke on it. Apparently, you are not doing that, so in reality HTML rules apply, `script` content is parsed as plain text, and the browser’s JavaScript interpreter gets literally `&gt;` and vomits. And in HTML mode, no matter what the doctype might seem to be saying, `CDATA` sections are just messy data.

So as @Quentin suggests, don’t do XHTML. If you actually *need* to use XHTML, use external scripts.